# How to see RAM contents of a running STM32 MCU without resetting it?

Tags: debugging, embedded, stm32, ram, iar

I have developed a project using IAR EW for ARM and an STM32 MCU. For an issue, I need to inspect the RAM contents of a running device. How can I do that without resetting the device? because with the reset RAM will be re-initialized and I will lose the data.

Comment: Debuggers usually offer "Hot connect" or similar mode, where the debugger connects to target without reset. Check your toolset's documentation.

Comment: Or just start the program with the debugger attached, which ought to be possible in most use-cases.

Comment: IAR have an option called connect a running target. But Couldn't make it work with my device.

Comment: . I want to see current RAM data of a block. I am suspecting it's corrupted and causing an issue. I am not able to reproduce the issue. Need to inspect RAM of a device with the issue to verify the theory.

Comment: Some information you are posting in comments belong in the question.  You never mentioned for example that you have an ST-Link or that you have tried and failed to _connect a running target_. Perhaps you should ask about why that would not work.  Also it is possibly an X-Y problem - you are asking how to implement what you believe to be a solution to a problem, and are asking how to make your solution work.  It may be more productive to discuss the problem rather than a possibly flawed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Reset does not modify or reinitialise the SRAM.  That occurs in the runtime start-up. The on-chip SRAM will *not* be reinitialised unless you let the run-time start-up code run (which executes between reset and `main()`).

So all you need do is set a breakpoint at the reset vector and maintain power and you can connect the debugger and let it reset. It will halt before anything writes to the SRAM, the content of which will be preserved through a reset so long as power is maintained.

The reset vector is stored at offset 0x0004 from the start of the vector table.  The address of that will depend on whether you are using ROM, Flash or SRAM boot mode (SRAM boot would of course be unhelpful in this case). It will also be the symbol __reset in your link-map. Anyhow you can set the symbol or the absolute address as a breakpoint *before* connection of the debugger, and it will halt before modifying SRAM.

Alternatively your debugger can almost certainly be configured to connect without asserting a reset (a long time since I have used EWB so I can't tell you exactly how - that is what the user manual is for), which would preserve not only the SRAM, but also the peripheral register states, the NVIC and core registers likely to be essential in many debugging situations. That said, you mention in a comment that you tried that without success.  I too have had issues "hot connecting" to STM32 - I have never *needed* the feature sufficiently to resolve that issue, and assumed it was a misconfiguration, but perhaps it is a "feature"?

Ultimately the best solution is to be running with the debugger connected from the get go, so you can simply halt the processor to inspect it's state, or in mast cases, view the memory "Luce" while the processor continues to run.

Comment: It is called - connect to running target

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset does not purge RAM.

If you want to connect to uC but you want it to continue running then you need to connect to the running target.

It is very easy in Keil and Eclipse based IDEs. IAR - you need to find option to disable loading program at startup and resetting the uC.

For Keil:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The OP mentions in a comment that he'd tried _connect a running target_ in IAR.  He may if course have tried it "wrong".  As you have shown, there are three configurations to get right in Keil, IAR may be similar.  Haven't used it in 15 years.

Comment: @Clifford  IAR  - I do not like it.